# SilverStripe updateSettingsFields() through DataExtension

Tags: php, silverstripe

The equivalent of `getCMSFields()` in a `DataExtension` is `updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields)`.

What's the equivalent for editing the settings fields through `getSettingsFields()`, for use in DataExtensions?

**non-dataextension example**

```
public function getSettingsFields() {
    $fields = parent::getSettingsFields();
    $fields->removeByName('visiblity');
return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getSettingsField` has an extend-call on `updateSettingsFields`, so on your DataExtension, you can make a method `public function updateSettingsFields(&$fields){}` to update the fields.

It works exactly the same as `updateCMSFields`, so no need for a return.

Comment: Yup, that's it. Also no more `parent::getSettingsFields();` necessary in the method body